# Check/Uncheck the checkbox by changing values in options in different rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a Table as follow

```
<tbody>
<?php 
foreach($redeemSales as $sale)
{ 
   ?>
   <tr>
      <td><form><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection" ></form></td>
      <td><?php echo $sale["ring"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo formatFullDate($sale["soldDate"]) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $sale["saleType"]; ?></td>
      <td>   
          <div class="col-lg-8">
                <select name="type" class="form-control redeemOptions">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="CD">CherieDori Credit (CD)</option>
                <option value="Amex">American Express Card (Amex)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

What I want is, when i select let's say default value of  is "None" .

When i select second option "CD" the checkbox get's selected automatically.

If i change to any other option, then it should get unselected automatically.

There are multiple rows and i want only corresponding checkbox to get selected.

Here is what i have tried in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{    
    $('.redeemOptions').change(function()
    {
        var menuChanged = $(this);

        parentForm = menuChanged.closest('form');
        correspondingCheckbox = parentForm.find('input[name=userSelection]');

        if(menuChanged.val() == 'CD') 
        {           
            correspondingCheckbox[0].checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            correspondingCheckbox[0].checked = false;   
        } 
    });
});
```

Now firstly, `correspondingCheckbox.checked = true;` is not working. How can I get it correct.

Secondly, if i press button, i want to get ids of all the rows that are selected. E.g 1st Row, 3rd Row etc

I have a button below the table

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="actions.php?j=5&saleIds=x,x,x,x">Redeem Sales &rarr;</a>
```

I want to send all the sale ids of the rows i have selected. `foreach($redeemSales as $sale)` Is the sale and its sale id can be get by `$sale['id'].` I need to maybe, add them in an array when i change the checkbox to true and then send it when clicking above a herf button. How will i do it in javascript where the selection is checked or maybe when button is clicked, it checks for all checked checkboxes and make a list and pass to actions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem maybe is the traversing of the checkbox. Based on the markup above, you could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.redeemOptions').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var status = (value == 'CD') ? true : false;
        $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].childNodes[0].checked = status;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection[]" ></td>
  <td>ring1</td>
  <td>2014-09-28</td>
  <td>type1</td>
  <td>   
      <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select name="type" class="form-control redeemOptions">
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="CD">CherieDori Credit (CD)</option>
            <option value="Amex">American Express Card (Amex)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection[]" ></td>
  <td>ring2</td>
  <td>2014-09-28</td>
  <td>type2</td>
  <td>   
      <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select name="type" class="form-control redeemOptions">
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="CD">CherieDori Credit (CD)</option>
            <option value="Amex">American Express Card (Amex)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Edit:

You should also put the sales id on the checkboxes:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="salesIds[]" value="<?php echo $sale['id']; ?>" /></td>
```

And then, on the JS:

```
$('.selection').on('click', function(){
    var checked = $('input[name="salesIds[]"]:checked').serialize();
    window.location.href = 'actions.php?j=5&' + checked;
});
```

The finally on the PHP thats going to process this, `salesIds` will be an array:

```
$_GET['salesIds'] // is now an array
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for that. There is a second part of question. How can i on button press, get all rows column ids, i-e it was first row or second. Mabye i can make a global array where i store when javascript if statement is true. but how can i do that

Comment: @MuhammadUmar can you paraphrase it a bit, can't understand what you mean, can you give a sample case?

Comment: hello @MuhammadUmar, what is the name of the `ID` in your table? `$sale["salesId"];`

Comment: i have currently added <tr  value='<?php echo $sale['id']; ?>'> so one can get id as value of tr

Comment: @MuhammadUmar i made some revisions

Comment: Thanks, that reallllly helped me a lot in understandings too